# Python - Comparing each item of a list to every other item in that list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to compare every item in a very long list (12471 items) to every other item in the same list. Below is my list:

```
[array([3, 4, 5])
array([ 6,  8, 10])
array([ 9, 12, 15])
array([12, 16, 20])
array([15, 20, 25])
...]                 #12471 items long
```

I need to compare the second item of each array to the first item of every other array to see if they're equal. And preferably, in a very efficient way. Is there a simple and efficient way to do this in Python 2.x?

---

I worked up a very crude method here, but it is terribly slow:

```
ls=len(myList)       #12471
l=ls
k=0
for i in myList:
        k+=1
        while l>=0:
            l-=1
            if i[1]==myList[l][0]:
                #Do stuff
        l=ls
```

Comment: Just do a back of the envelop calculation: you have n^2 comparisons to do with n=10^7. If one comparison takes only 1ns it will still take a full day.

Comment: do you know anything about range of values that those arrays contain? is there any additional info available about possible values of those array elements?

Comment: @Kevin They are all pythagorean triples. I'm not sure if that helps.

Comment: what is the max value an element can take? is it MAX_INT or is there any other upper limit like number won't be more than 10000 let us say?

Comment: @Kevin They max value any item can be is set. For the question is it 10^7. But it can be changed to be much more manageable if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is still theoretically N^2 time (worst case), it should make things a bit better:

```
import collections

inval = [[3, 4, 5],
[ 6,  8, 10],
[ 9, 12, 15],
[ 12, 14, 15],
[12, 16, 20],
[ 6,  6, 10],
[ 8,  8, 10],
[15, 20, 25]]

by_first = collections.defaultdict(list)
by_second = collections.defaultdict(list)

for item in inval:
    by_first[item[0]].append(item)
    by_second[item[1]].append(item)

for k, vals in by_first.items():
    if k in by_second:
        print "by first:", vals, "by second:", by_second[k]
```

Output of my simple, short case:

```
by first: [[6, 8, 10], [6, 6, 10]] by second: [[6, 6, 10]]
by first: [[8, 8, 10]] by second: [[6, 8, 10], [8, 8, 10]]
by first: [[12, 14, 15], [12, 16, 20]] by second: [[9, 12, 15]]
```

Though this DOES NOT handle duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this in O(N) with an assumption that python dict takes O(1) time for insert and lookup.

1. In the first scan, we create a map storing first number and row index by scanning the full list
2. In the second scan, we find if map from first scan contains second element of each row. If map contains then value of map gives us the list of row indices that match the required criterion.

```
    myList = [[3, 4, 5], [ 6,  8, 10], [ 9, 12, 15], [12, 16, 20], [15, 20, 25]]

    first_column = dict()
    for idx, list in enumerate(myList):
        if list[0] in first_column:
            first_column[list[0]].append(idx)
        else:
            first_column[list[0]] = [idx]

    for idx, list in enumerate(myList):
        if list[1] in first_column:
            print ('rows matching for element {} from row {} are {}'.format(list[1], idx,  first_column[list[1]]))
```